# How to put image in place of checkbox if checkbox is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The code is working fine but I want to replace those checkbox with image or icon which is disabled. So, How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list-dis input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).closest('tr').index() !== 0) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }).on('change', function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list-dis" id="sub1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="1">

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="2">

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="3">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess you can wrap it with a div, and when a condition is fulfilled, you set that div's innerHTML to be a icon instead of a checkbox.

Comment: you can create it without any js with css pseudo :disabled :checked [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list-dis input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).closest('tr').index() !== 0) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', true).hide()
      $(this).next().show()
    }
  }).on('change', function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', false).show()
    .next().hide()
  });
});
```

```css
.list-dis img { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list-dis" id="sub1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="1"><img src="http://aux.iconspalace.com/uploads/1062253611720440079.png" width="20"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="2"><img src="http://aux.iconspalace.com/uploads/1062253611720440079.png" width="20"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="3"><img src="http://aux.iconspalace.com/uploads/1062253611720440079.png" width="20"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to put icon or image in place of disabled checkbox before it check

Comment: As per your code when I check checkbox then checked chekbox is hide but I want to show image in place of those checkbox which is disabled before check

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.list-dis input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                if ($(this).closest('tr').index() !== 0) {
                    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                }
            }).on('change', function() {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                
                $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', false);
               $(this).prop('outerHTML', '<img src="" width="10px" height="10px"/>');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="list-dis" id="sub1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="1"> 

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="2"> 

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="test" id="3"> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can change attribute values of `<img>` tag inside `<script>`

Comment: I want to show image in place of those checkbox which is disabled before check

Comment: is before =  upward or before = background?

Comment: sorry I can't get you

Comment: Do you want to change background of disabled checkboxes? Or you want to put image there and replace it with checkbox when user mark check-box above it?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for helping me again :) I remember you. That was a mistakenly pressed Ctrl+C